# Can't install Stripe API. APEX Classes required

Tags: apex, error, enterprise, stripe

I'm trying to integrate Stripe with my Salesforce account but everytime I try to install the API dependency I get multiple errors requiring APEX Classes. I'm on a trial period for an Enterprise account, if that helps.

I'll leave some screenshots below to better illustrate this error.

I've tried all users and Admins only, had the same results.

Sorry for the screenshots being in Portuguese.

I hope you guys can give me a north here, I'm going into the fourth day trying to make it work.

I also tried adding the permissions on the permissions group, that didn't help.

[image: API Version I need to install]

[image: It's in Portuguese but, I selected ADMINS ONLY]

[image: This package can't be installed]

Comment: Have you checked with Stripe support?

Comment: Not yet. I did not think this could be a Stripe issue since it's requiring some APEX Classes. I'm trying to be sure it's not related to Salesforce before moving on to another supports

Comment: You are installing this package? https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=4dff0f8e-0b10-47c2-a3a3-f3905e7f7927 -- this is the one their doc lists

Comment: when you are in the installation screen, click on Advenced option. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aav2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aav2.png) Then choose the second option that means: compile with just the test class in the package and not in all your org. after you choose this option click on install. Successfully!

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately got the same error :(

Comment: If the Apex classes are part of the managed package, then you need to contact Stripe support.